# Displaying certain word count for multiple files in bash

Tags: regex, bash, arguments, word-count

So i am trying to write a program that counts how many instances in a file a word appears in a certain file. I am able to to find how many times one word with one file by

```
a=`grep -c $1 Samplefile.txt`
echo "you matched: $a times for word $1 "
```

how would i do this for multiple files.
The first thing I got to work used a sample input of
    (Program1 word file). this next requirement needs me to be able to do Program2 word file1 file2 for input

Answer (score 0):

Just use shel glob to make grep run for multiple files:

```
grep -c "$1" *.txt
```

Here this `grep` will run for all `*.txt` files instead of just `Samplefile.txt`

Output will be like this:

```
abc.txt:3
Samplefile.txt:5
xyz.txt:0
```

Alternatively you can do same in for loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    grep -Hc "$1" "$f"
done
```

**EDIT:** As per comment if you want to run it for known set of file then use

```
for f in "XXX" "YYY"; do
    grep -Hc "$1" "$f"
done
```

Comment: What would happen if i only wanted to run it for 2 files and i have 3 files in the directory. so I have file XXX file YYY and file ZZZ but i only want to run it for files XXX and YYY.

Comment: In that case you can just run grep twice as `grep -c "$1" XXX` and `grep -c "$1" YYY`

Comment: so just use a for loop? how would the program know to only do it twice ? the program is supposed to handle whether you type in prog1 word file or prog1 word file1 file2.

Also thanks in advance for all your input!!

Comment: see edited code on how to run a for loop for 2 files only. It is awfully late here will check further comments in the morning only.